# What is $\inf(\mathbb R_+^\times\cap G)$?

Tags: general-topology

Given a non-trivial subgroup $G\subset\mathbb R$ (with respect to +) such that $\inf(\mathbb R_+^\times\cap G)=d>0$, I need to show that $G=\mathbb Zd$.

What is $\inf(\mathbb R_+^\times\cap G)$?

Comment: It's the greatest lower bound, or infimum of $\mathbb{R}^\times_+\cap G$

Comment: What is $R_+^×?$ @Max

Comment: @WilliamElliot . It means $\Bbb R^+$ (sometimes written $\Bbb R_+$) which is the set of all positive reals. The superscript $\times$  seems to  be a typo

Comment: The superscript $\times$ indicates that we're not taking $0$. $\mathbb{R}_+ = \{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\geq 0\}$, $\mathbb{R}^\times =\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\neq 0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}_+^\times = \mathbb{R}_+\cap\mathbb{R}^\times$